# Snow Leopard hide scrollbar in terminal?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app

Is there a way to get rid of the scrollbar in Terminal.app in SN (it worked with earlier versions of OSX, but so far I didn't get it working on 10.6)

Comment: FYI: I've always wanted this myself, so I just took a quick look at the plist. No relevant option seems to be there.

Comment: This other question has a good answer without having to get a different product http://superuser.com/questions/418990/scroll-bar-on-os-x-lion-terminal-wont-go-away

Answer (score 1):

[iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) is a free Terminal replacement for OS X and it lets you hide the scroll bar. Has a bunch of other features Terminal.app doesn't have as well (tabs, bookmarks, transparency, etc.).

Comment: There is also an alpha release of iTerm2: http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/

Comment: How stable is that release? I was looking at that the other day. The alpha tag scared me off. But I like the idea of switching to, supporting, a alt terminal that is actually developed. iTerm feels pretty much abandoned these days.

Answer (score 1):

As of OS X Lion 10.7 scrollbars can be hidden system-wide, including in Terminal, with

> System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars

If you have a “touch” input device, like a trackpad or Magic Mouse, they are hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy Terminal app from an old OS X version ([source](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=5670665)). You could also try editing the interface NIB file.

**Edit**: I'm not certain the NIB approach would work, but I think that is where interface elements are defined.

Comment: I don't know anything about Cocoa apps. Care to share where an application's NIB file would live? Thanks.

Comment: NIB files can be edited as described here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081121083323825. I'd start by looking at the Terminal.app NIB here: /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/TTWindow.nib But as my edited comment suggests, this is just a guess and would be a considerable hack if it did work...

Comment: I just took a look inside all of the nib files in the resource folder and none have a scrollbar. TTWindow just has a blank window and some menus... scrollbar is probably done programmtically. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LionScrollbars](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41429/lionscrollbars). It's the only thing that worked for me. Works like a charm under 10.8.2.