# Scroll Bar on OS X Lion Terminal won't go away

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app, scrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Snow Leopard hide scrollbar in terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/178424/snow-leopard-hide-scrollbar-in-terminal)

I have this scrolling bar on the right side of my terminal because I accidentally split the window and I've merged the windows, quit the terminal, and restarted my computer, and this evil thing won't go away.

It's not really in the way but when it's in full screen or window it's there and it's annoying.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem, please file a bug report [Apple Bug Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) or provide feedback [Mac OS X Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried going into OS X System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars: and unchecked always?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I turned it on always then turned it back off.